# Creating Hit Counter

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, web

I am trying to create a hit counter in VBScript on a HTML Page for specific client needs. I cannot use any hit counters available for free.

My problem is that my code only finds the text file on my notebook (Local C:\ drive) and not in the website, even though the file does exist. My other problem is that when the page code reaches the `server.creatobject` line, I get the error `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'server'`.

I write mostly in VB but the client wants a specific HTML page and NOT ASP/ASPX. Can someone help me please? I have been trying for a while and cannot get a decent answer to my above questions.

Below is the code.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">

Dim fso
dim tso
dim FilObject
dim VisitorCount
dim strOutputName
dim objOutputfile
strfilename ="counter.txt"

set fso=server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")


set filobject=fso.getfile(strfilename)
set tso=filobject.openastextstream

visitorcount=clng(tso.readall)
visitorcount=visitorcount + 1
stroutputname=strfilename
set objoutputfile=fso.createtextfile(stroutputname,true)

objoutputfile.writeline visitorcount

document.write(visitorcount)
</script>
```

Comment: You're at the wrong site. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: You are in a dead end. Your client want something that can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

> ...the client wants a specific HTML page and NOT ASP

But you have written an ASP script (`runat="server"` using the VBScript scripting language). The `Server` object is only available in ASP. Your file will need to be a `.asp` file (or somehow processed by the server as ASP), otherwise your script will be run as client-side VBScript and the `Server` object will not be available, which is the error you appear to be getting.